# How can I format every java exception to not write logger for each line?

Tags: java, exception, jboss, jvm, wildfly

I have found in my application, some java exceptions are thrown in different lines purely, just with a `'\n'` char, but others are printed with the full decorator of the logger.

Sample of first ones:

```
16:15:01,732 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1337) UT005023: Exception handling request to /api: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key test (attempted merging values {cuid=test} and {cuid=test2})
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:78)
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:222)
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193)
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:455)
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
```

Sample of second ones:

```
 13:21:24,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10) org.influxdb.InfluxDBIOException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
 13:21:24,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10) at deployment.myear.ear//org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.execute(InfluxDBImpl.java:638)
 13:21:24,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10) at deployment.myear.ear//org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.query(InfluxDBImpl.java:544)
```

Is there anyway to configure either java, jvm, jboss(wildfly) or anything that allows me to print all the exceptions with the simple `'\n'` format?

Comment: Please, provide some information about a logger you employ and it's config.

Comment: Doesn't matter my logger. Both exceptions I showed come from 3rd parties that print this, probably with standard printStackTrace(), not sure. The thing is, I do not wan't to fix my own Exceptions, but EVERY single exception, no matter who throws it. That's why I link it to jvm maybe. I'm not really sure if it is possible

Comment: It seems, in the first case, the exception has not been caught, hence no `printStackTrace()` performed. So JBoss wrapped it in an `UnhandledException` and *logged* the exception. In contrast, in the second case someone caught the exception but did `printStackTrace()` instead of logging. So the logging facility can only report that someone printed something to `[stderr]`, without even knowing that it is a stack trace.

Comment: @Holger is correct. Those are being written to `System.err` which is wrapped by a logger named `stderr` which is why each line is printed as a separate log message.